# Startswith exact word match in elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, prefix

I have an index containing field **title** having data as below.

1. jam bread
2. jamun
3. jamaica country

So If user searches for **jam**, I don't  want **jamun** and **jamaica country** also come in search result. Right now I am using prefix query in elasticsearch, but it is not giving me result as I want.

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "title" : "jam" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get both the results as prefix query actually runs a regexp query `(keyword*)` on the inverted index so both the results will match.

you can do something like the following and use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) instead of the prefix query to do the exact match on the tokenized keyword.

```
PUT exact_index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "title" : {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST exact_index1/document_type
{
  "title" : "jamun"
}

POST exact_index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title": {
        "value": "jam"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But it will also fetch data like "fruit jam" also in response. I want results starting with exact word jam.

Comment: yes, well in that case its all about getting the most relevant on the top. "fruit jam" should match as per term query but its order should be lower than "jam" or "jam brown".

Answer (score 0):

The completion suggester provides **search-as-you-type** functionality

```
PUT - index_name/document_type/_mapping
{
"document_type": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "search_analyzer": "simple"
        }
      }
   }
}

POST - index_name/document_type
 {
    "name": "jamun",
    "suggest":
    {
        "input": "jamun"
    },
    "output": "jamun"
 }

POST - index_name/document_type/_suggest?pretty

{"type-suggest":{"text":"jam","completion":{"field":"suggest"}}}
```

Comment: Is there any way to index data in the below order as "apple iphone 6" as "apple","apple iphone","apple iphone 6"  using shingle or something?

Comment: @LijoAbraham you can index data in any order. Elastic search query return the data search as you type like [app, appl, apple, apple i, apple iphone, apple iphone 6]

Comment: I need only word ngrams. not "appl" or "i"